# Update my.cnf auto_increment_offset with last character of hostname

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I need to take the hostname of the machine and grab the last character.  In this example the hostname is:  web-01

I want to get the "1" from the hostname.  This command will also be used on web-02, etc.

I have this working pretty well with:

```
hostname | awk '{print substr($0,length,1)}'
```

After I get that number I need to update a file.  In this case I need to update the following line:

```
auto_increment_offset = 0
```

And it should become:

```
auto_increment_offset = <the last character of the hostname>
```

I was attempting to do this portion with:

```
sed -i "/^auto_increment_offset/s/0/$1/" /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf;
```

Full command I am attempting to run:

```
hostname | awk '{print substr($0,length,1)}' | sed -i "/^auto_increment_offset/s/0/$1/" /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
```

For some reason it isn't working and I need to step-out for a bit, so I figured I would ask for help.  That's it.  Please inform me that I am an idiot and assist me in making this work.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified your command a bit, this one works for me:

```
sed "/^auto_increment_offset/s/=.*/= ${HOSTNAME#${HOSTNAME%?}}/" /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf;
```

Comment: you are my favorite person.  thank you very much.  i love the simplification.  i knew there was a better way to go about it and you nailed it.  thx.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for... I just took what you wrote, and wrote some sed inside sed. I often use this sort of trick to work around similar problems - even if it's not very succinct. Otherwise gergoerdosi's answer is nicer imo.

`hostname | awk '{print substr($0,length,1)}' | sed -e "s%\(.*\)%sed -i \"/^auto_increment_offset/s/0/\1/\" /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf %" | sh`